# Swing Custom GUI Component

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I need to create a custom GUI Component about same like shown in the following image.
it has some buttons and labels on this.

How can i create like this

[image: Custom java Swing image like this]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a JWindow, with an Image for the background picture. For the buttons, use a JButton with an ImageIcon.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a JFrame with nullLayout then use a JLabel with the image.

Now for buttons use setContentAreaFilled(false) and setBorderPainted(false) to remove the default button style and it will look exactly like the image that you have passed while creating the button.

To position the Frame at the center use setLocationRelativeTo(null) .

I think that should solve your problem.

Comment: Disagree with the recommendation to use null layout. I would recommend that the OP use a combination of nested layouts and let the images and preferred component sizes help the managers find the best layout.

Comment: Just to emphasize @Hovercraft: *nooooo!* null layout is a no-no-never-ever in swing.

Comment: Thanks for the comments :) I am still a beginner in java and learning things :) Will keep your recommendations in mind. Can you please just tell me why not to use null layout ?

Comment: For several reasons, but for one your GUI appearance can be awful to non-functional on different platforms or even on different resolutions. For another, it makes it very difficult to upgrade your GUI, such as if you wish to add another button.