# JPanel on JWindow, adding components

Tags: java, swing, jdialog, jwindow

I have a `JFrame`, inside the `JFrame` code I create a `JWindow` and on window I have created a `JPanel`. On `JPanel` is inserted a background image.

```
JButton btnImage= new JButton("My Button");

 Image splashImg = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("images/image1.jpeg");
    
JPanel pnlSplashWindow= new JPanel(){ 

        public void paint(Graphics g){
          g.drawImage(splashImg,0,0,splashImg.getWidth(this),splashImg.getHeight(this),this);
    }
    };
    
    pnlSplashWindow.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    pnlSplashWindow.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH,btnImage);
    JWindo window= new JWindow(this); // this refers to my class which has extended JFrame

    window.setContentPane(pnlSplashWindow);
    window.setSize(688, 344);
    btnImg.setVisible(true);
    window.setLocationRelativeTo(this);
```

I am new to `JWindow` and have the following questions:

1. How to add elements like buttons and labels on `JWindow` (or `JPanel` which is on the `JWindow`)?
2. How to set my `JFrame` as the parent of this `JWindow`? I mean while `JWindow` is active, the `JFrame` should not be clickable.

#### An example of the desired end effect

[image: Example of splash]

Comment: `JWindo window= new JWindow(this); // this ..` is not code that would compile.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add components you should use:

```
pnlSplashWindow.add(btnImage, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

instead. And if you don't want your JFrame to be clickable, you should use a **modal** `JDialog` , by extending [`JDialog`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html) instead of `JWindow`.

But if you want to create a Splash Screen, you should read [How to create a Splash Screen](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html).

Comment: i want to create welcome screen, that has a checkbox, wither to show on start up or not.

Comment: Are you still trying to create (something like) the GUI shown on [Swing Custom GUI Component](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981446/swing-custom-gui-component)?

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: Thanks , yes i am trying to create same like that. :)